Where is list of application overrides for Thunar ( xfce ubuntu 24.04)
Where is the list of local default application overrides for Thunar, sometimes called FileManager which is part of Xubuntu 24.04?

Are you referring to the application that is run when opening a file of a certain type? If so, then https://github.com/sandsmark/selectdefaultapplication may help

That's what I was looking for.  As part of migrating from Xubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 (fresh install on new harddrive) - I wish to copy each 'user' or ID's decision as to what application should open specific file types (jpg, png, epub, txt, html etc)
